# Java Code never entering try block in try-catch

Tags: java, web-services, service, client, try-catch

I am currently creating a project to write a client and service that give information from a music database.

I have created a MusicService.java file which is deploying fine. I am not sure if the code is right however. I then needed to create a client. When I run the client I keep getting Error Faults thrown from my try catch in my MusicService.java class saying("Unable to find composer") or ("unable to find disc") From doing some basic debugging, I know that the try methods in getByComposer and getByDisc are never being entered and going straight to catch.

I also know in my client.java method that the try is being entered due to my print statement being returned in console. However the code is never executing and going straight to the catch exception and I can't work out why.

I know there is a mistake somewhere perhaps I am not calling but I have spent hours on this and can't seem to find the problem.

I will leave the 2 methods underneath, if anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

MusicService.java method

```
package music;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class MusicService extends MusicServiceSkeleton {

 private final static String databaseHost = "mysql0.cs.stir.ac.uk";
 private final static String databaseName = "CSCU9YW";
 private final static String databasePassword = "rtk1";
 private final static String databaseUser = "rtk1";
 private final static String discTable = "music";


//define methods to implement the WSDL opeartions getByComposer() and getByDisc()

 public music.MultipleTracks getByComposer(music.Composer composer)throws ErrorFault
 {
     try {
         TrackDetail[]info=getByField("composer",composer.getComposer());
         MultipleTracks multiTrack = new MultipleTracks(); 
         TrackDetails multiRetrieve = new TrackDetails(); 
         multiRetrieve.setTracklist(info);
         multiTrack.setMultipleTracks(multiRetrieve);
         return multiTrack;
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         throw(new ErrorFault("Unable to find composer"));
     }
 }

 public music.MultipleTracks getByDisc(music.Disc disc)throws ErrorFault
 {
     try {
         System.out.println("hello in getbbydisc");
         TrackDetail[]info=getByField("disc",disc.getDisc());
         MultipleTracks multiTrack = new MultipleTracks(); 
         TrackDetails multiRetrieve = new TrackDetails(); 
         multiRetrieve.setTracklist(info);
         multiTrack.setMultipleTracks(multiRetrieve);
         return multiTrack;
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         throw(new ErrorFault("Unable to find disc"));
     }
 }



    private TrackDetail[] getByField(String field, String value) throws ErrorFault {
        try {
            if (value.length() == 0)
                throw (new Exception(field + " is empty"));
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            String databaseDesignation = "jdbc:mysql://" + databaseHost + "/" + databaseName + "?user=" + databaseUser
                    + "&password=" + databasePassword;
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseDesignation);
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            String query = "SELECT disc, track, composer, work, title " + "FROM " + discTable + " " + "WHERE " + field
                    + " LIKE '%" + value + "%'";
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(query);
            result.last();
            int resultCount = result.getRow();
            if (resultCount == 0)
                throw (new Exception(field + " '" + value + "' not found"));

            TrackDetail[] trackDetails = new TrackDetail[resultCount];
            result.beforeFirst();
            int resultIndex = 0;
            while (result.next()) {
                TrackDetail receiver = detailsReceived(result);
                trackDetails[resultIndex++]= receiver;
            }
            connection.close();
            return (trackDetails);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            String errorMessage = "database access error - " + exception.getMessage();
            throw (new ErrorFault(errorMessage, exception));
        }
    }
    private TrackDetail detailsReceived(ResultSet current)throws SQLException
    {
    TrackDetail details = new TrackDetail();
    details.setDiscNumber(current.getString(1));
    details.setTrackNumber(current.getString(2));
    details.setComposerName(current.getString(3));
    details.setWorkName(current.getString(4));
    details.setTitleName(current.getString(5));

    return details;
    }

}
```

The Client.java method

```
package music;

import music.MusicServiceStub.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Client extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private final static int contentInset = 5;
    private final static int trackColumns = 130;
    private final static int trackRows = 20;
    private final static int gridLeft = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    private final static String programTitle = "Music Album";

    private GridBagConstraints contentConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    private GridBagLayout contentLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    private Container contentPane = getContentPane();
    private JButton discButton = new JButton("Check");
    private JLabel discLabel = new JLabel("Disc Number:");
    private JTextField discText = new JTextField(5);
    private JButton nameButton = new JButton("Check");
    private JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Composer/Artiste Name:");
    private JTextField nameText = new JTextField(16);
    private Font trackFont = new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 12);
    private JLabel trackLabel = new JLabel("Tracks:");
    private JTextArea trackArea = new JTextArea(trackRows, trackColumns);
    private JScrollPane trackScroller = new JScrollPane(trackArea);
    private MultipleTracks tracks;


// define here private variable for your Client Stub


    public Client() throws Exception  {
        contentPane.setLayout(contentLayout);
        addComponent(0, 0, gridLeft, nameLabel);
        addComponent(1, 0, gridLeft, nameText);
        addComponent(2, 0, gridLeft, nameButton);
        addComponent(0, 1, gridLeft, discLabel);
        addComponent(1, 1, gridLeft, discText);
        addComponent(2, 1, gridLeft, discButton);
        addComponent(0, 2, gridLeft, trackLabel);
        addComponent(0, 3, gridLeft, trackScroller);
        nameButton.addActionListener(this);
        discButton.addActionListener(this);
        trackArea.setFont(trackFont);
        trackArea.setEditable(false);

// instantiate your Client Stub and assign to private class variable declared above

}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int screenWidth = screenSize.width;
        int screenHeight = screenSize.height;

        Client window = new Client();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setTitle(programTitle);
        window.pack();
        int windowWidth = window.getWidth();
        int windowHeight = window.getHeight();
        int windowX = (screenWidth - windowWidth) / 2;
        int windowY = (screenHeight - windowHeight) / 2;
        window.setLocation(windowX, windowY);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addComponent(int x, int y, int position, JComponent component) {
        Insets contentInsets = new Insets(contentInset, contentInset, contentInset, contentInset);
        contentConstraints.gridx = x;
        contentConstraints.gridy = y;
        contentConstraints.anchor = position;
        contentConstraints.insets = contentInsets;
        if (component == trackArea || component == trackLabel)
            contentConstraints.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        contentLayout.setConstraints(component, contentConstraints);
        contentPane.add(component);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String trackRows = "";
        TrackDetail[] tracks;
        try {
            //System.out.println("Hello");
            if (event.getSource() == nameButton)
                tracks = getField("composer", nameText.getText());
            else if (event.getSource() == discButton)
                tracks = getField("disc", discText.getText());
            else
                return;
            trackRows += String.format("%4s %5s %-32s %-40s %-40s\n", "Disc", "Track", "Composer/Artist", "Work", "Title");
            for (int i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
                TrackDetail trackDetail = tracks[i];
                trackRows += extractMusicData(trackDetail);


// extract the data for a track and append to trackRows variable


            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            String error = exception.getMessage();
            if (error == null) error = exception.toString();
            error = "could not get track - " + error;
            trackRows += error;
        }
        trackArea.setText(trackRows);
    }

    private String extractMusicData(TrackDetail track )
    {
        String albumName= track.getWorkName();
        String composer = track.getComposerName();
        String title= track.getTitleName();
        String trackNo= track.getTrackNumber().toString();
        String discNo= track.getDiscNumber().toString();

        String extractMusicTracks= String.format("%4s %5s %-32s %-40s %-40s\n", discNo, trackNo, composer, albumName, title);
        return extractMusicTracks; 
    } 

    private TrackDetail[] getField(String field, String value) throws Exception {

// define behaviour for method getField() to call the web service methods and receive the results
    try 
    {
        TrackDetail[] multiTrack; 
        MusicServiceStub stub=new MusicServiceStub();

        if(field.equals("disc"))
        {
            MusicServiceStub.Disc requestDisc = new MusicServiceStub.Disc(); 
            requestDisc.setDisc(value);
            MusicServiceStub.MultipleTracks message= stub.getByDisc(requestDisc); 
            multiTrack= extractedTracks(message);
            return multiTrack; 
        } else if(field.equals("composer"));
        {
            MusicServiceStub.Composer requestComposer = new MusicServiceStub.Composer(); 
            requestComposer.setComposer(value);
            MusicServiceStub.MultipleTracks message= stub.getByComposer(requestComposer); 
            multiTrack= extractedTracks(message);
            return multiTrack; 
        }
    } catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
return null; 
    }


    private TrackDetail[] extractedTracks(MultipleTracks tracks)
    {
        TrackDetails track= tracks.getMultipleTracks();
        TrackDetail[] multiTrack= track.getTracklist(); 
        return multiTrack;
    }
    }
```

Comment: You did not post the exception.

Comment: In each catch you need to get info from the underlying exception, like e.printstacktace(), to know from where the issue is comming. Do that and add the your findings to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your error handling is way off:

1. Idiomatic java dictates that exceptions end in the word 'Exception'. Don't use the name 'ErrorFault'. Aside from being non-idiomatic, that's a tautology.
2. When rethrowing, pass the cause, and lose the parens: `throw new ErrorFault("Unable to find composer", e);` except don't name it ErrorFault. Now you can check what is causing java to jump to the catch block.

Note that java does not randomly jump to catch blocks for no reason. Something in that try block is throwing, and you're hiding the cause by throwing something else without passing the original along as cause.

3. Don't ever catch exceptions and just do 'System.out.println(e)' - code is going to continue afterwards, even though clearly the process is now in an invalid state. If you have no idea how to handle an exception, your best bet is to just add a 'throws' clause on your method to throw it onwards. If that is just not an option and you also don't feel like wrapping it in an appropriate exception either, the absolute fallback is `throw new RuntimeException(e)`, not `e.printStackTrace()`, or even worse, the information-obliterating `System.out.println(e);` - update your IDE's templates!

Once you apply the above advice, the problem should be clear. If it is not, at least now you get a stack trace that includes a lot more detail; post that as a question here (or update your question) with that info and perhaps someone can help you figure out what's going on.